# iOS app authentication - if it's possible to use Apple id

Tags: ios, authentication

I'm pretty newbie in `iOS` development but I'm trying to figure out how to organize the authentication. I need the authentication because of 2 reasons:

1. In-app purchases
2. User can add his or her own data into common database.

I supposed that as soon as user downloaded my app he or she will be easier to use the Apple id to authenticate but I have no idea if it's possible to use Apple id in this situation and how to organize this authentication on my server.

For information: I'm going to use `Node.js` as a backend with `MongoDB`, hosted on `Windows Azure` portal.

The workflow is:

1. User downloads and runs my app
2. User uses it (without any authentication so far)
3. If user wants to add his new data and share it the data should be
   sent to the server and user must enter some credentials.
4. User enters Apple id credentials (and user name under he wants to
   share data?) and sends his data to the server.
5. Further if he wants to do app-in purchase he uses the same
   credentials.

If it's even possible? If I can't use Apple credentials to send data to my server, if it's possible to use other credentials (my email, or `OAuth`) to make app-in purchase? I don't like to idea to make user enter different credentials twice.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at CloudKit, in particular [CloudKit Web Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference) and/or [CloudKit JS](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkitjs). On the one hand, these are more about interfacing from your native app hosted web app to user content/sharing in iCloud than about authentication, but they might still be helpful. See [developer.apple.com/icloud](http://developer.apple.com/icloud) for more docs and useful WWDC talks.

Comment: Thanks @rickster I will definitely look at this services.

Comment: @mimic I am looking for the similar solution. Did you find the answer to your problem. Currently, I am using Google sign in API for sign in purpose. Can we use Apple Id credentials for the user to sign in?

Comment: @UtsavDusad No, I didn't find anything. I asked on the Apple dev forum and the only piece of advice I'd got there was to use as many credentials as I want "because it's not bad at all" :(